# Google Org Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, orgchart

I try to change 
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjGcx.png)

To this line to connect to bottom node like this
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZlvd.png)

How can I do it, which part that I need to change in this line of code

```
 data.addRows([[{ v: 'department' + department, f: '' }, 'division' + division, department, 'department', 'department' + department]]);
```

this code created the node look like in picture 1.
It is possible to connect from Level 1 to Level 3 without Level 2
For example SBU to Department not Division to Department
Like this http://jsfiddle.net/36gg3ro1/262/
I want Bob to connect with Mike but his level is lower than Jim and Alice

Edit: It working now to solve this problem I create CSS style so change the empty node to become the line

Comment: just not possible using google's org chart...

Comment: ok, I think so because I can't find any option in a document to solve my problem

Comment: Can you recommend which tool will possible? @WhiteHat

Comment: not really sure, maybe [vis.js](http://visjs.org/index.html), check out the network examples...